# how to create blank embedded document in mongodb by php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to initialize an object in mongodb like this

```
{"_id":"123","name":"JACK","data":{}}
```

array and map is the same thing in php, so when I save this

```
$a = [ 'name': 'JACK', 'data': [] ]
```

I got this

```
{ "_id": "123", "name": "JACK", "data": [] }
```

Question: how to create blank embedded document in mongodb by php

there are to different document

```
{ "_id": "123", "name": "JACK", "data": {} }
{ "_id": "123", "name": "JACK", "data": [] }
```

the same command in MongoDB shell will do different thing

```
db.test.update( { "name": "JACK" }, { "$set": { "data.5": 1 } } )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are beginning PHP with mongodb, you may want to take a look at [this](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/24960636131/mongodb-for-the-php-mind-part-1)

If you want to represent this:

```
{
  "_id":"123",
  "name":"JACK",
  "data":{}
}
```

You could do this in PHP:

```
$emptyObj = new \stdClass();
$doc = array(
    '_id' => '123',
    'name' => 'JACK',
    'data' => $emptyObj
);
```

Comment: thanks, but I mean to get a blank embedded document .
you can get {"_id":"123","name":"JACK","data":{}} very easy . it's different in bson. but {} and [] is same in php

Comment: Checkout my changed answer

Comment: Your'e Welcome. I'm glad I could help!